# Mongoose query get selector key

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an example query

```
User.findOne({ $or: [{ name: val }, { username: val }, { email: val }, { phone: val }] }, (err, user) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log(user, selector: ???);
});
```

How can I know which key was the selector (name, username, email or phone?)

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the code for that mean.

There is an option if you want to see the execution plan of your query you can set an option in `mongoose.find()` like this:

`Mode.find(query).setOptions({explain: 'executionStats'}).then(executionPlan => {console.log(executionPlan)});`

And see the result if it has any useful information for your need.